# Problems with pivot table

Tags: python

I am trying to create a pivot table. I have the next code:

```
table1 = pd.pivot_table(df1, values=['6. Senderismo', '6. serv Ciclismo','6. serv Hospedaje',
                                   '6.  serv Restaurante','7. Cabalgatas','6.  area picnic','7. Caminatas']
                       ,columns=['13. razón Recreación'], aggfunc=np.sum)
table1
```

I got the following table:

[image]

Comment: What is your question, what your problem?

Comment: The table does not have the sum for rows of elements